# One line proof for a maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

My question is very simple but I'm looking for a one-line proof.

I want a simple argument to justify that $\int_{-1}^1 y^2 e^{\frac{-(y+x)^2}{2}}dy$ is maximized at $x=0$. I don't think that computing derivative is necessary for that, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^2}dy$$
is symmetric in $x$, and therefore $x=0$ is a critical point. However, I don't think you can infer that it is a maximum without computing the second derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Actually I think it can be argued just by analysing the behaviour of the function composition....